# How to use callback function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, callback

I have a array **$services** and this array contains below values :

```
Array
(
  [0] => One way
  [1] =>  Hourly
  [2] =>  To Airport
  [3] =>  From Airport
  [4] =>   Birthday
  [5] =>  Wedding
  [6] =>  Concert
  [7] =>   Sporting Event
  [8] =>   Cruise Party
  [9] =>  Funeral
)
```

You can notice that some of values in array contain space.
To remove this space from array values I created a array_walk function which walk into array and trim the white space.

```
public function trim_value(&$value) {
     $value = trim($value);
}
```

As you all know that the syntax of array_walk function is :

```
array_walk($array, 'callback_function');
```

Now I want to use this function in codeigniter controller. As I know that a function in controller is being used as $this->function in another function.
So I tried to use callback function as :

```
array_walk($services, $this->trim_value);
```

It always throws an below error :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> ```
> <p>Severity: Notice</p>
> <p>Message:  Undefined property: Attribute::$trim_value</p>
> <p>Filename: controllers/attribute.php</p>
> <p>Line Number: 230</p>
> ```

So can somebody tell me that how to use callback function in one of controller's function ?

Comment: No, I don't agree with you because there are many inbuilt function in php library that are used with callback function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to pass `array_walk()` an array with `$this` as a defined `variable/pointer`.

Try this

```
array_walk($array, array($this, 'trim_value'));
```

Comment: Beat me to it - I just found that in http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php and tried it out - It works!